# Patch request to COSMOS DB: 404 not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb

Updated: Solved by Sajeetharan's suggestion! Thanks.

I'm trying to implement the api to partially update cosmos db. I got 404 not found when I tested this patch request. I tested query in cosmo's db, it's working as expected. I don't know which part is wrong.

Comment: where are you invoking patch?

Comment: If Sajeetharan's answer works for you please mark it as the answer. Please click the check mark right beside the answer to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invoke the [`Patch`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/cosmosdb/cosmos/samples/v3/typescript/src/ItemManagement.ts#L182) on the container as how you have done fetchAll request.

Here is a sample,

```
const multipleOperations: PatchOperation[] = [
  {
    op: "add",
    path: "/aka",
    value: "MeFamily"
  },
  {
    op: "replace",
    path: "/lastName",
    value: "Jose"
  },
  {
    op: "remove",
    path: "/parents"
  },
  {
    op: "set",
    path: "/address/zip",
    value: 90211
  },
  {
    op: "incr",
    path: "/address/zip",
    value: 5
  }
];
const { resource: patchSource2 } = await container.item(patchId!).patch(multipleOperations);
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure have confusing error message for this.

1. Check you are operating on the right container
2. Check partition key is correct
3. If you add adding new field, don't forget the '/' in "/newfield"